# C# Use a method from a base class with a different parameter

Tags: c#

I've already research a lot about the question and already know the direct answer. You can't override a base method with new parameter. Thing is, what I want to do is simple yet I don't know what to look for or if what I want to do is non-sense so if anybody can point me to a direction that would be great.

Here's what I want to do. I have a base class with a method call Create. This methods takes a **Type** argument and uses reflection to create the associate object with its properties. Its works great with whatever type I pass as an argument but now **I want this method to return the said type pass in the parameter to add it to a list**. Naturally I just added a return to the created model but I can't add a Type object to my List Student (*My own type here*). So what I tried was to create a derived class and in that class change the parameter from Type to Student. Obviously this doesn't work but now I am stuck. My base method works perfectly (other than the fact it doesn't return what I want) and I would like to only modify the return type on my derived class. Here's the snippet of the code. (NOTE: I am french)

```
abstract class ControllerBase
{
    public virtual Type Create(ControlContainer controlContainer, Type typeToCreate)
    {
        dynamic returnObject = null;

        //Stuff that creates my returnObject

        return returnObject;
    }
}

class StudentControl : ControllerBase
{
    static public List<Student> Students{ get; set; }

    public Type Create(ContainerControl containerControl, Type typeToCreate)
    {
        typeToCreate = typeof(Student);
        return base.Create(containerControl, typeToCreate);
    }
}
```

So, this is basically what I want to do. Transform the return type of my base method to another type in my derived class in order to add it to my Student list. I've looked around but don't really what to look for here. *I can't use a `<T>` generic method here because reflection doesn't work on generic type*.

Comment: If you can make this generic, this is where generics come in. Change your return to be of type `T`, and in your caller, specify the type you expect to be getting back. Change all usages inside the `Create` method to use `T` instead if you can.

Comment: Alright ill take note, thank you!

Comment: The "Type" class is not the base class of all classes. It's a descriptor that holds the metadata of classes, structs and interfaces etc. You can never cast or "transform" a "Type" object into any object you like. Your class "Student" does not extend "Type". Please read about polymorphism.

Comment: Your Create(...) method signature never allows to return  an instance of e.g. "Student" only the type's metadata e.g. instanceOfStudent.GetType():Type. Why would you want to create an instance without returning it? A "Type" is created by defining e.g. a class. Instance of this type is created by using "new"-keyword or reflection. You have to make "Create()" return an "object" at least or introduce a base type. 'object Create(args) {}. Then cast return type to "Student" or use generics!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who said that reflection doesn't work with generics?

```
abstract class ControleurBase
{
    public virtual T Créer<T>(ConteneurControle conteneurControle)
    {
        var actualType = typeof(T); // use this instead of the Type parameter
        dynamic modele = null;

        //Stuff that creates my model  

        return (T)modele;
    }
}

class ControleurÉtudiant : ControleurBase
{
    public static List<Étudiant> Etudiant { get; set; }

    public Étudiant Créer(ConteneurControle conteneurControle)
    {
        return base.Créer<Étudiant>(conteneurControle);
    }
}
```

By the way, you really shouldn't write code that's not in English. It makes it hard for anyone who doesn't speak French.